# Error importing confluence xml dump, PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "content_pkey"

Tags: postgresql, confluence

PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "content_pkey" Key (contentid)=(1220) already exists.

The error occurs when I import data. I have looked at the official solution, but my data volume is too large, is there any other solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Backup%Restore option (https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/restoring-a-space-152036.html) for import , so the options can be:

1. Change the ID inside the .XML.ZIP file so that it will not conflict with the one inside the Confluence (but please note that you will have to edit all the metadata of the export file so that it will not break)
2. Archive the page with PageID=1220 and later recreate so that it will not conflict with import

If you have a lot of IDs crossing each other, you can think of changing them inside the DB, but usually it is not a good option as it has a lot of tables using it.